# Ssh-keygen not generating key

Tags: ssh-keygen

I am trying to create a public key to allow me to push to Git but my .ssh folder isn't being created.

The following are my commands I have run:

- $ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C emaill@me.com
- Generating public/private rsa
  key pair.
- Enter file in which to save the key (/h//.ssh/id_rsa):

This is all that is in the H: drive
config, data, profile, profile.V2

I think there is an issue because when I get the prompt 'Enter file in which to save the key (/h//.ssh/id_rsa):', I am not given a chance to enter a value or press enter, nor a choice to enter a passphrase.

Can any suggest what might be the issue? I've tried running the command in verbose mode but it prints nothing extra.

Comment: On some windows installations, I had to copy my .ssh folder to different locations after generating a ssh key.

Possible locations were: H:\.ssh C:\Users\<user>\.ssh and C:\Users\<user>\Documents\.ssh
Maybe the file wound up in some other folder?

Comment: @AlexR I checked but nothing is in any of those suggestions. Wouldn't I be prompted about passphrase if a file was created? I suspect Git installation is corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have some kind of permissions issue, try making the folder manually

```
mkdir -m 700 ${HOME}/.ssh
```

If your trying to create your keys on another drive that you have mounted then you could try copying your keys manually.

If it's on a completely different system then maybe you could try

```
ssh-copy-id
```